# T-Sql Implicitely combine one of more tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sas

Is there a way to implicetly combine one or more tables in T-SQL? I am coming from a SAS background and if wanted to stack more than one table with different number of columns and names, SAS was smart enough to know that col x wasn't in table y so it would null all those values.

For example, from the SAS documents (see Example 1):
[SAS Example](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1tgk0uanvisvon1r26lc036k0w7.htm)

```
OBS  Common  Animal  Number       OBS  Common  Plant     Number

 1     a     Ant       5           1     g     Grape       69
 2     b     Bird                  2     h     Hazelnut    55
 3     c     Cat      17           3     i     Indigo       .
 4     d     Dog       9           4     j     Jicama      14 
 5     e     Eagle                 5     k     Kale         5
 6     f     Frog     76           6     l     Lentil      77
```

to combine these two table is as simple as:

```
data concatenation;
   set animal plant;
run;
```

With T-SQL all I have been able to find so far to combine these two sets, is to explicitly list out and null all the values in the select statement.

Like so, example (a):

```
select obs, common, animal, null as plant, number
from animal
union all
select obs, common, null as animan, plant, number
```

Now if the plants and animal tables had the same column names it would be easy as example(b):

```
select * from plants
union all
select * from animals
```

Now, my question is, is there a way to combine mismatched tables with T-SQL that is as easy as the SAS example or will I have to explicitly define any mismatches like in example (a).

Comment: It's not so much the column names--but for UNION you have to have the same number of columns and the columns have to be the same datatype as the corresponding column in the first SELECT.

Comment: Pretty sure you have your answer in example a, I don't think there's an equivalent in sql.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent in SQL Server, so you have to use example (a).

You need to make sure all fields have the same datatype. Try using the convert (or cast) function to make your example (a) working. I don't know your datatypes so you just made a guess, you can adapt this example with your correct datatypes.

```
select convert(int, obs), 
       convert(nvarchar, common), 
       convert(nvarchar, animal), 
       convert(nvarchar, null) as plant, 
       convert(decimal(16,2), number)
from animal
union all
select convert(int, obs), 
       convert(nvarchar, common), 
       convert(nvarchar, null) as animal, 
       convert(nvarchar, plant), 
       convert(decimal(16,2), number)
from plant
```

Answer (score 0):

My impression is no.

If you did have an existing table that had all of the possible columns then you could use INSERT to add the records from tables with subsets of the columns.

```
 insert into concatenation (Common,Animal,Number)
   select Common,Animal,Number from animals
 ;
 insert into concatenation (Common,Plant,Number)
   select Common,Plant,Number from plants
 ;
```